# How to prevent the execution of a method in the new activity during Intent in Kotlin Android

Tags: android-intent, kotlin

I have SignUpActivity.kt, LoginActivity.kt and ProfileActivity.kt. In SignUpActivity.kt I use Intent to start LoginActivity.kt and in LoginActivity.kt I use Intent to start ProfileActivity.kt.

SignUpActivity.kt

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)
...

already_have_account_text_view.setOnClickListener {
startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
finish()
}
```

LoginActivity.kt

'''

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
...

login_button_login.setOnClickListener {
performLogin()
}

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val user = auth.currentUser
            updateUI(user)
        } else {                    
            updateUI(null)
        }                
    }

public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()        
 val currentUser = auth.currentUser
 updateUI(currentUser)
}

private fun updateUI(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {
    if(currentUser != null) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java))
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Login failed", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

'''

The program is running properly but the message of toast "Login failed" is showed up during the Intent. Which is should not be like that. The updateUI function must be only execute when login button is clicked.

Another problem if I let it like that, when the user register in the SingUpActivity, the user will be directed to ProfileActivity. Which should be like that. I want the user to Login after sign up.

How can I make the execution of updateUI function not during the Intent but only when user click the login button?

Comment: You should delete the updateUI() method call from the onStart() method if you want to call that method only on a button click.